# How can I size a Table control that I put on a CTabFolder Item?

Tags: shell, swt

When I put the Group that contains the Table on the Tab Item it is sized very small. How can I adjust its size?

Here is my code:
How can I size a Table control that I put on a CTabFolder Item?

```
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(556, 553);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");

    CTabFolder cf = new CTabFolder(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    cf.setBounds(24, 21, 392, 330);
    cf.setSelectionBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_INACTIVE_BACKGROUND_GRADIENT));

    CTabItem tabItem = new CTabItem(cf, SWT.NONE);

    Group group = new Group(cf, SWT.NONE);

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    group.setLayout(layout);
    Table table1 = new Table(group, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

    TableItem ti = new TableItem(table1, SWT.NONE); 
    ti.setText("Item 1");
     ti = new TableItem(table1, SWT.NONE);
    ti.setText("Item 2");
     ti = new TableItem(table1, SWT.NONE);
    ti.setText("Item 3");

    tabItem.setControl(group);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `GridData` in the table layout data to tell the grid layout how to deal with the table.

This:

```
table1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

will give the table all the available space.

For spacing the `GridLayout` has `marginWidth` and `marginHeight` fields you can set or set `marginLeft`, `marginRight`, `marginTop`, `marginBottom` individually.

Comment: How would I put a margin or padding around the Table/Group, so that it does not fill the whole Tab but has some space around it, or on top of it?

Comment: Added `GridLayout` margin info to answer